# Ensure delivery of message, RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, enterprise-integration

I know the common approach is to create consumers queue before publishing message, but it seems pretty tight coupling going on here, generally I don't want to know how many queues consuming from this exchange and how much messages each of them get, how can we preserve the reliability while decoupling the server from consumer?

[image]

On this image the client-app still needs to know if there are any server queues available to process auth request. Because if there is no queues the message will be dead lettered, I don't believe that no one ever though about this? Or we presume that this queues always exists (they are durable)?

Answer (score 1):

The way that RabbitMQ and AMQP 0.9.1 in general works is to not couple the sender of the message to the consumer.  You can query the exchange using many different methods to find out what queues are bound to it, but at the time that you send the message you are never sure what exactly is available unless you actually create the queue and the binding yourself.

One way that you can check for sure that a message was not placed onto a queue is to use [publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html).  Another possible asynchronous way is also to listen for the notification on the standard RabbitMQ logging exchange that your message was DLQ'd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***queue-pooling*** in order to guarantee reliable message delivery. In this case, the client application does not need to explicitly know about available Queues - it simply asks the `QueuePool` for the next available Queue. Should the `QueuePool` become exhausted, the QueuePool will return a Queue in a manner defined by the client through a high order function. More info [here](http://insidethecpu.com/2015/07/31/microservices-in-c-part-2-consistent-message-delivery/).